# Cannot Read File Datadog Agent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, file-permissions, datadog

After following this guide to setup dd-agent permissions for log files https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/setting-file-permissions-for-rotating-logs/, I still get:

```
- Type: file
  Path: /home/ubuntu/Projects/livestream/nohup.out
  Status: Error: cannot read file /home/ubuntu/Projects/livestream/nohup.out: stat /home/ubuntu/Projects/livestream/nohup.out: permission denied
  BytesRead: 0
  Average Latency (ms): 0
  24h Average Latency (ms): 0
  Peak Latency (ms): 0
  24h Peak Latency (ms): 0
```

I have confirmed the permissions are set:

```
# file: Projects/livestream/
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
user:dd-agent:r-x
group::rwx
group:dd-agent:r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx

ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-150:~$ getfacl Projects/livestream/nohup.out 
# file: Projects/livestream/nohup.out
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
user:dd-agent:r-x
group::---
group:dd-agent:r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx

getfacl Projects/
# file: Projects/
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
user:dd-agent:r-x
group::rwx
group:dd-agent:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x

sudo systemctl restart datadog-agent
sudo datadog-agent status
```

What could be going on that it cannot read the file?

Comment: these are the file permissions, what are the folder permissions?

Comment: You mean the Projects folder? It's right there the last one.

Comment: are you sure that the agent is being run by `dd-agent` user?

Comment: Did you find a explanation of the problem? I am not able to undertand why this setings are not working and I am interested in explanation, instead of a workaround

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 22.04. I solved this by adding dd-agent on the Ubuntu group:

```
sudo usermod -aG ubuntu dd-agent
```

Comment: Same, in my case I added to the group with my user's name.

Comment: Yeah, nice! this makes the trick, we face this issue after updating our DD_AGENT to today's latest version (7.46.0) on Ubuntu 22.04.